# Flex 4, dynamic chart

Tags: xml, apache-flex, dynamic, flex4, charts

How can I create a dynamic chart with multiple series when my XML looks like this and the number of series nodes could be more or less depending on the data.

```
<root><series id="Americas" name="Americas">
<item total="2" year="2011" month="April" fullDate="April 2011"/>
<item total="3" year="2011" month="February" fullDate="February 2011"/>
<item total="2" year="2011" month="March" fullDate="March 2011"/></series><series id="Asia-Pacific" name="Asia-Pacific">
<item total="2" year="2011" month="April" fullDate="April 2011"/>
<item total="1" year="2011" month="January" fullDate="January 2011"/>
<item total="1" year="2011" month="March" fullDate="March 2011"/></series><series id="EMEIA" name="EMEIA">
<item total="1" year="2011" month="April" fullDate="April 2011"/>
<item total="1" year="2011" month="February" fullDate="February 2011"/>
<item total="3" year="2011" month="March" fullDate="March 2011"/></series><series id="Global" name="Global">
<item total="3" year="2011" month="April" fullDate="April 2011"/>
<item total="3" year="2011" month="March" fullDate="March 2011"/></series></root>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [this example](http://www.flex-blog.com/flex-dynamic-chart/) could help you. From his post:

> Using arrays as objects in my
>   dataProvider (of type
>   ArrayCollection), I am able to
>   dynamically add and remove key / value
>   pairs to or from that array.

He also includes the example's [source code](http://www.flex-blog.com/samples/sample13/srcview/index.html) for you to take a look at.